# How to set the xpath for a element in html using python selenium webdriver

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver

```
<div id="div_1" class="info-container">
  <div class="name" data-toggle="dropdown"><div>
  <div class="name" data-toggle="dropdown"><div>
  <div id="div_2" class="btn-group user-helper-dropdown">
     <i  class="material-icons" data-toggle="dropdown" 
      aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"></i>
     <ul id="div_3" class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
       <li><a href="/profile/user/view"><i class="material
              icons">person</i>Profile</a></li>
       <li role="seperator" class="divider"></li>
       <li id="sgn_out"><a id="sign_out_button" href="/sign-out"><i
           class="material-icons">input</i>Sign Out</a></li>
     </ul>
  </div>
<div>
```

Hello I am having trouble in find the `XPath` for the tag which has `id='sign_out_button'` in selenium webdriver in Python.

This is the what I have tried:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='div_1']/div[@id='div_2']/ul[@id='div_3']/li[@id='sgn_out']/a")
```

But it gives me an error like this:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element:
Unable to locate element: 
{"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@id='div_1']/div[@id='div_2']/ul[@id='div_3']/li[@id='sgn_out']/a"}
```

Comment: There is no `<div id="div_1" ...>` element in that html.

Comment: @JohnGordon My mistake. Now it's fixed

Comment: `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='sign_out_button']")` should be enough to find the sign out link. Or simply `driver.find_element_by_id("sign_out_button")`

Comment: Do you get the same exception with `driver.find_element_by_id("sign_out_button")` or `driver.find_element_by_link_text("Sign Out")` ?

Comment: @Andersson yes I'm getting same error for all the types you have mentioned here

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to invoke `click()` on the element with `id='sign_out_button'` as it is a dropdown item you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* as follows:

- `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul.dropdown-menu#div_3 li#sgn_out>a#sign_out_button"))).click()
  ```
- `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='dropdown-menu pull-right' and @id='div_3']//li[@id='sgn_out']/a[@id='sign_out_button']"))).click()
  ```